# Records in mnesia

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I have the following small table in Erlang mnesia database. When I use the dirty_select function as follows:

```
mnesia:dirty_select(user, [{#user{id = '$1', name = martin}, [], ['$1']}]).
```

I get the error:

```
* 1: record user undefined
```

The user table has one row with user id as primary key and 'martin' as the name of the user.
When I use the following command, it works well:

```
mnesia:dirty_read(user, 1).
```

And the output is:

```
[{user,1,martin}]
```

What could be the reason for the above error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are getting this error when using the erlang shell, you will need to define the record.  records are a compile time construct and the shell does not have access to their definitions.

```
1> rd(user, {id, name}).
user
2> #user{id=1, name="foo"}.
#user{id = 1,name = "foo"}
3> mnesia:dirty_select(user, [{#user{id = '$1', name = martin}, [], ['$1']}]).
...
```

once you have defined the record, your dirty_read operation will print the result using record syntax.

Comment: instead of defining the records using rd/2, you can also read the definitions from the source file with rf/1.  type help(). in the shell for more information.

Comment: I think you mean rr/1 for reading the record information from file! Anyway, it works when I read the record info from file before the select command, but is this the only way to solve this? I mean, do i need to read the record info every time i need to issue a query to the data base?

Comment: No, you need to read record info once per shell session or when you change it.